# Если источник null то мапить byte array тоже в null

Tags: c#, automapper

Есть проблема с маппингом поля типа byte[8]. Если значение поля источника равно null, то автомаппинг присваивает полю приемника значение 0x00000000. Можно как-нибудь сделать, чтобы полю приемника в этом случае также присваивался null?

```
source = {
 id = null
}

var fld= _mapper.Map<source>(request);

//получаем fld.id = 0x00000000000, а надо null
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Наверное без разницы byte[8] или byte[], просто в sql базе это значение хранится в binary(8), а в c#, соответственно byte[]. sourse.id имеет тип  byte[]. И нужен именно null

Comment: Да! Спасибо,  A K, сработало!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подсмотрено на [en so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8408612/5752652):

```
Mapper.Configuration.AllowNullCollections = true;
```

Это ещё со второй версии автомаппера поддерживается, а сейчас вот [на днях](https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-9-0-released/) девятая вышла, так что у вас проблем с тем, что не та версия вряд ли будет.